# how to apply a transparent background to png which adhere's to Technet specs?

Tags: gimp, paint.net

Okay, so after fooling around with an image I can not figure out how to get this image: [image]

to be with a transparent background  for usage with the TechNet documentation here which requires a certain colored  image with transparency or gradient to be listed with a

> specific RGB color code

: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825696.aspx

Go to the Customize Help Home -> Home Page - simple section -> To perform a simple customization section. 
I have my help files but only need a proper image with transparent background color. How do I do this? I would prefer paint.net instructions. 
Here's the section in quotes I am talking about:

> Format: .png file that has a transparent background or a gradient that
>   matches the RBG TileColor color specified in the unattended-Setup
>   setting.

Other Notes: Tell me the RGB color code used if at all. Its not only about transparency without the correct color code the image WILL NOT display as suggested in the help and support article. I did not make up those rules Microsoft did.

More Information: I am adding the registry entries which contains the RGB color code I am using so their is no more confusion. Its simple: if the logo picture is 145*80 and has transparency and the correct background color it would appear. Here's a picture:
[image]

I've already tried obvious simple operations as shown here (one to start out with and I will add more I have tried later):

[image]

Here's the second picture I tried with transparency and a white background. I even have a black dot I tried to use on the left part of the picture.
So, that may stump some people claiming that I can use "any" color in the picture (Edit: I may be able to use "any" but right now I am as stumped as you).

[image]

Comment: You mention you want a white background, but you also want transparent background, you can't have both.

Comment: Well I want a white background if it adheres to the section in gray above otherwise please do transparent.

Comment: Think of transparent as being the color "clear"... Allowing whatever is underneath to show thru.

Comment: I am trying to get an image to adhere to the gray though. I'll change to transparent in the title if you think that's easier to accomplish and have adhere to the gray part.

Comment: I think you largely don't know what you asking.  "Adhere" to what?  It not like wall paint.

Comment: I want a white transparent background which will adhere to the TechNet quote in gray above. I changed the title to show something more specific. I want transparency in my image but I may need to start a new question if this does not work. It should though if done properly.

Comment: "White transparent" can't be, it's either white, or its transparent. It can't be both.

Comment: Can I make a transparent red then?

Comment: Think of transparent as its own color, it's not red, it's not white, it's clear.  With clear you see the color or colors of the image or background behind this Image.

Comment: Okay, have transparency then that shows all the way back to a red background image. Otherwise, if I am still wrong surprise me with a color in the background of my selected image that adheres to the technet instructions.

Comment: According to the instructions, you need a PNG file with a transparent background or a gradient that matches the RBG TileColor color specified in your Unattend.xml file. So just search the net or better still the Paint.NET forum for a tutorial to create a PNG with a transparent background, and whatever colour you choose to be transparent include it in your Unattend.xml file. Seems pretty straight-forward to me.

Comment: I've tried the layer and alpha mask trick suggested on here but maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: P.S. the registry entry seems to match the suggested unattend.xml file setting (I am basing it off of the OEM information section of the registry). I actually going off the seat of my pants on the registry entry.

Comment: @Karan, if it were that easy you could make a logo and answer that would work in help and support. It's not because I made a transparent PNG only and it failed to work because theirs no way to know the RGB color code. I even put a black background, still fail. I even found a tutorial on here using the alpha mask plugin for paint.net which still failed.

Comment: Not my job to make the logo. "theirs (sic) no way to know the RGB color code" - The way I know transparent pixels work, you need to select any particular colour in the image as transparent, because obviously there's no "transparent" colour that can be applied. So for example if the background is pure red, select that as the transparent colour and you have your corresponding RGB values as (255, 0, 0).

Comment: I already did that with a black color, so... why repeat my last comment except add red to the end? :/ I'll get an image with a black background behind the transparent one and show you what I am talking about above for reference. (RGB 0,0,0 and it still does not work).

Comment: I have one with the squid transparent with black background still.

Comment: To all who claim "white transparent can't be" and such: think of the pixels as RGBA quadruplets. (255, 255, 255, 0) is white transparent in this context. Yes, this means that transparent pixels can keep their original colors, this works for e.g. PNG, TGA, TIFF and BMP (oh, yes.  much fun to be had with this, actually), depending on application support for each of them. For PNG, there's also a special chunk to set the background color, bKGD - GIMP sets this to the current background of the main color chooser when exporting PNG by default.

Answer (score 0):

The spec is really only a guide to help you produce a coherent visual style.

What is says is that the image should somehow “relate” to the `TileColor`, even if not transparent. That’s all. **You can choose whatever color you like.**

The requirements are that you supply the following attributes with valid values:

- `Manufacturer`
- `Logo`
- `TileColor`

Only then will your tile appear.

If you want to remove the black background from your image, I suggest GIMP’s “Color To Alpha” tool.

Comment: I've tried black and white color values and get nothing to show up. If you want to test what I am trying to do, try to place any color in your picture in TileColor and it doesn't work! Note: I am using a registry edit not a sysprep answer file. So, it would be very appreciated if you post an working example because I've tried many different approach's that should have worked according to your example.

Comment: I'll try the sysprep but its been awhile since I've sysprepped but can still remember some things.